# Issue filtering woocommerce products in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Morning! this should be an easy one, I'm trying to filter products by 'Region' but my args don't seem to have any effect on my woocommerce product list generated from this query? Please help much appreciated.

```
$args = array(
    'type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        '_stock_status' => 'instock',
        'Region' => 'Mexico'
    )
);
foreach ( wc_get_products( array( $args, 'limit' => -1 ) ) as $product ) {

    foreach ( $product->get_attributes() as $attr_name => $attr ) {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to change R to r

```
 'Region' => 'Mexico' change to   'region' => 'Mexico'
```